# Python Selenium: change the visiblity of the element from hidden to visible then click?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have a website that I want to scrape sold house listings on https://www.zealty.ca/search.html.

Everything is working fine (at least for the first 3 pages). But the website is currently limiting me scraping the succeeding pages.This is what the javascript code looks like on the site

[image]

Notice the code currently has `visibility: hidden`. However, I noticed that if I were to manually change `visibility: hidden` to `visiblity: visible`, the button would pop up.

Is there anyway to make this button "appear" on Python such that I can allow the script to click on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("element").style.visibility = "visible";);
```